# Adding Media Queries to Javascript

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I've got a sticky sidebar going on with this code. But I only want it to affect the .fake-sidebar div when at 768px or below. Could anyone explain how to add media queries to my javascript?

```
var sticky_offset;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var original_position_offset = $('.fake-sidebar').offset();
    sticky_offset = original_position_offset.top;
    $('.fake-sidebar').css('position', 'fixed');
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var sticky_height = $('.fake-sidebar').outerHeight();
    var where_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var window_height = $(window).height();     

    if((where_scroll + window_height) > sticky_offset) {
        $('.fake-sidebar').css('position', 'relative');
    }

    if((where_scroll + window_height) < (sticky_offset + sticky_height))  {
        $('.fake-sidebar').css('position', 'fixed');
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Personally, I think utilizing http://modernizr.com/ is the best route... Modernizr allows you to easily do exactly what you are asking to do.

Comment: Have you looked at `window.matchMedia`? http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

You can add the event on `window resize`, or on `document ready`, depending of what you want:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 768) {
            $('.fake-sidebar').css('position', 'relative');
        }
        else {
            $('.fake-sidebar').css('position', 'fixed');
        }
    });
```